# Resampling 2-d array using Fourier transform method

Tags: python, arrays, image, gis, fft

I have a question on the resampling 2-d array.
Sometimes, the original size of the geoscience data should be transformed to other size. If the ratio for each axis is equal, the task is simple, in which `np.reshape` allow a 2-d array of 100x100 to 50x50 without data loss. The code is shown as:

```
## creat a original data 
xc1, xc2, yc1, yc2 = 100, 110, 35, 45
XSIZE,YSIZE=100,100
lon,lat  = np.linspace(xc1,xc2,XSIZE),np.linspace(yc1,yc2,YSIZE)
pop = np.random.uniform(low=1000, high=50000, size=(XSIZE*YSIZE,)).reshape(YSIZE,XSIZE)

## reshape
shape = np.array(pop.shape, dtype=float)
coarseness = 2 # the new shape is in 50 x 50
new_shape = coarseness * np.ceil(shape/coarseness).astype(int)
zp_pop = np.zeros(new_shape)
zp_pop[:int(shape[0]), :int(shape[1])] = pop
temp = zp_pop.reshape((new_shape[0] // coarseness, coarseness,
                                new_shape[1] // coarseness, coarseness))
coarse_pop = np.sum(temp, axis=(1,3))
print (pop.sum())
print (coarse_pop.sum())
```

However, when the coarse factor is different for each axis, this method can not be implemented. I turned to apply other method. Here is an example I tried to use FFT to generate a 60*80 array as output

```
from scipy import fftpack
pop_fft = fftpack.fft2(pop,shape = (60,80))
pop_res = fftpack.ifft2(pop_fft).real

print(pop.sum())
print(pop_res.sum())
```

```
254208134.8356425
122048754.13639387
```

The data loss was significant. Thus, I posted my issue here. Maybe the resampling function I used was not correct. Or there are some better approach to deal with this situation. Any advices or comments are highly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just implement reshaping manually like you did for the 100x100 -> 50x50 case. Only difference is if you've got to treat each axis separately.

Answer (score 2):

When you set up the 'coarse array' yourself you sum over adjacent entries, instead of computing the average or interpolating.

This way the sum over all elements in the coarse and original array are identical `str((coarse_pop.sum()-pop.sum())/(0.5*(pop.sum()+coarse_pop.sum())))` gives `'-1.1638426077573779e-16'` only a tiny numerical error.

if you compare the mean of the fftpack resampled coarse array it matches up:
    print(pop.mean())
    print(pop_res.mean())

```
25606.832220313503
25496.03271480075
```

alternatively you can correct for the number of elements yourself:

```
print(pop.sum())
print(pop_res.sum()*100*100/(60*80))

256068322.20313504
254960327.14800745
```

I don't know about your problem but the fftpack way of downsampling the array makes more sense to me. if it's not what you want you can apply the prefactor to the original array, like `pop_fft = fftpack.fft2(pop*100*100/(60*80),shape = (60,80))`